# How to make css left and right responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am trying to make my modal to be responsive.
I am currently using "right: 405px" in css to make my modal to stick in the right section.
However, the position of the modal keep changes as the screen size of the browser changes, which means this is not responsive.
In the attached screenshot, you can see the "Google Translator Modal" when the "info icon" is clicked. 
Could anyone help me write a responsive CSS code?

Thank you.

[image]

```css
.google-translator-modal {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10000;
  right: 405px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="google-translator-modal" style="display: none">
  <span class="upward-white-triangle"></span>
  <div class="google-translator-modal-content">
    powered by
    <a class="google-logo-link" href="https://translate.google.com" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_42x16dp.png" width="60px" height="20px" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-left: 3px" alt="Google Translate">
      Translate
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use percentages

Comment: @j08691 I tried using percentages but it wasn't responsive.

Comment: @mohade Adding "margin:0 auto" in the css code did not work.

Comment: I submitted an answer but just realized you might not want it horizontally centered - can you confirm where you want it to display across devices?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what is and isn't supposed to be _"responsive"_ here. Replying _"did not work"_ is not actionable feedback. I'm also not entirely sure what the expected result should be. Could you please clarify.

Comment: @hungerstar Thank you very much for your response.I have attached the screenshot to the description of the question. In the screenshot, you can see the "Google Translator" modal when the "info icon" is clicked. That is where I want to place the modal.

Comment: @hungerstar I tried your answer, but your answer below breaks the structure of the page...

Comment: I haven't provided an answer. From you screenshot it looks like you want to create more of a tooltip than a general modal. For this I would define your _"modal"_ inside the markup for the icon and/or _"Select Language"_ and use absolute positioning to pull it out of the container element.

Comment: Can you try using bootstrap? It is more powerful and responsiveness is great

Answer (score 0):

This a crude example but it ultimately comes down to positioning an absolute positioned element inside of a relative positioned element and showing it on hover.

I have placed the *"modal,"* what I would call a tooltip, inside of the element that appears to be triggering it's appearance. By placing the tooltip inside and relative to the element that triggers it, we don't have to worry about how far from the edge of the viewport we are. The tooltip will always be position relative to the icon in my example.

```css
.translate {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 1.5rem;
}

.translate-icon {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.translate-icon:hover .translate-tooltip {
  display: block;
} 

.translate-tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1.75rem;
  right: -0.35rem;
  width: 13rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.translate-tooltip::before,
.translate-tooltip::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: 0.25rem;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: solid transparent;
}
.translate-tooltip::before {
  border-bottom-color: gray;
  border-width: 9px;
}
.translate-tooltip::after {
  border-bottom-color: white;
  border-width: 8px;
  right: calc( 0.25rem + 1px );
}
```

```html
<div class="translate">
  Select Language 
  
  <span class="translate-icon">&omega;
    <div class="translate-tooltip">
      Powered by Google Translate
    </div>
  </span>
  
</div>
```